# Using a web domain or system path URL to access a file in PHP

Tags: php, apache, localhost, httpd.conf

I have a localhost Apache/PHP configuration on my computer. I want to be able to

1) check the existence of an image file using an absolute path and

2) display it using the same URL

A simple example of something I want to do:

```
if(file_exists($url)) {
    echo '<img src="' . $url . '" />';
}
```

if I set...

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/myimg.jpg';
```

then file_exists will return false, because the URL is a web path (http://localhost/myimg.jpg).

---

if I set...

```
$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myimg.jpg';
```

it will recognize that the file exists (C:/htdocs/myimg.jpg), but fail to display the image because it cannot access the image source. If I view the source and copy/paste the URL into the web browser's address bar, the image is displayed just fine.

---

Perhaps I'm missing something in Apache's httpd.conf file, or PHP.ini? Maybe an Alias declaration of some sort. Also, the site will be uploaded to a remote web server (such as bluehost.com) when it is complete, so I need a versatile solution.

allow_url_fopen in PHP.ini is On, and I've been restarting the server every time I make a change in either httpd.conf or PHP.ini. I've been struggling with this for days, so even a point in the right direction would be very appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing server side file access with client side.

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/myimg.jpg';
```

This produces a URI to be used by the client to fetch your image via HTTP. For example `http://example.com/myimg.jpg`

---

```
$url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myimg.jpg';
```

This produces a filesystem path to be used by PHP. For example `/var/www/htdocs/myimg.jpg`

---

Your solution needs to use both

```
$img = '/myimg.jpg';

if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $img)) {
    echo '<img src="', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $img, '" />';
}
```

Edit: You could probably replace the `echo` line with

```
echo '<img src="', $img, '" />';
```

as an absolute URL (one beginning with a forward slash) always starts at the document root

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "/myimg.jpg";
if( file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$url))
    echo "<img src='".$url."' />";
?>
```

This will give you the HTML:

```
<img src='/myimg.jpg' />
```

Which is the image since it resolves from the domain name.

Comment: FYI, the PHP concatenation operator is `.`

Comment: Oops... I really should go to bed >_>

Answer (score 0):

An absolute path, which `file_exists` takes, is completely different from your web path. You'll just need to use separate paths for `file_exists` and your `src` attribute in your `img` tag.

```
$img = 'myimg.jpg';
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $img) {
    echo '<img src=' . $img . ' />';
}
```

Comment: You're assuming here that the image file is in the same location as the current URI which may not be the case. The OP indicates the image sits in the document root.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but the point was to illustrate that the OP could not use the same path for both purposes.